# Delete name from List while clicking a Button

Tags: java, android

I'm new in Android Studio and I have a problem.

As you can see on a screenshot, while user writes a name and click 'Add' button, new layout appears with this name and button to delete it.
[Screen to add players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv460.png).

Now, when I go to the next screen clicking 'Go further', all names are visible. The problem appears when I want to remove some name clicking 'Delete' button, e.g. I want to remove David. David shouldn't be visible on the next activity. Unfortunately he is. 
[Next activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v86J.png).

And this is my code:

TeamNamesActivity

```
public class TeamNamesActivity extends Activity {

Button button_more_players;
EditText namesBlueTeam;
Button addPlayersBlueTeam;
LinearLayout containerBlueTeam;
EditText namesRedTeam;
Button addPlayersRedTeam;
LinearLayout containerRedTeam;
int shortestNameLength = 3;
ArrayList<String> names_blueTeam = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> names_redTeam = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_names);
    namesBlueTeam = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_player_blue);
    namesRedTeam = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_player_red);
    addPlayersBlueTeam = (Button)findViewById(R.id.more_players_blue_team);
    addPlayersRedTeam = (Button)findViewById(R.id.more_players_red_team);
    containerBlueTeam = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container_blue);
    containerRedTeam = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container_red);
}

public void addMorePlayers_blueTeam(View view) {
    button_more_players = (Button) findViewById(R.id.more_players_blue_team);
    addPlayers(namesBlueTeam, containerBlueTeam, names_blueTeam);
}

public void addMorePlayers_redTeam(View view) {
    button_more_players = (Button) findViewById(R.id.more_players_red_team);
    addPlayers(namesRedTeam, containerRedTeam, names_redTeam);
}

public void addPlayers(EditText nameOfPlayer, LinearLayout container, List<String> playersNames) {
    final View addView;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(nameOfPlayer.getText().length() >= shortestNameLength) {

        addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_to_add_more_players, null);
        TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);
        String currentName = nameOfPlayer.getText().toString();
        textOut.setText(currentName);
        playersNames.add(currentName);

        nameOfPlayer.setText("");
        Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
        buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
            }
        });
        container.addView(addView);

    }
}

public void goFurther(View view) {

    Intent teamNamesIntent = new Intent(this, StartGameActivity.class);
    teamNamesIntent.putExtra("names_redTeam", names_redTeam);
    teamNamesIntent.putExtra("names_blueTeam", names_blueTeam);
    startActivity(teamNamesIntent);

}

public void goFurtherWithoutNames(View view) {
}

public List<String> getNames_redTeam() {
    return names_redTeam;
}

public List<String> getNames_blueTeam() {
    return names_blueTeam;
}
}
```

StartGameActivity

```
public class StartGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> names_redTeam;
ArrayList<String> names_blueTeam;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_game);
    TextView textOut = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textout2);
    names_redTeam = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("names_redTeam");
    names_blueTeam = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("names_blueTeam");
    textOut.setText("Red: " + names_redTeam + " ;;;;;; " + ", Blue: " + names_blueTeam);
}
}
```

Layout to delete

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button android:id="@+id/remove"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/remove_player"
    />

<TextView android:id="@+id/textout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/remove"
    />
```

Do you know how I can correct it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're adding names to `names_blueTeam` and `names_redTeam`, and showing the content of these lists.

The problem is when you perform a delete, you don't remove the corresponding name from them, so they still appear in the next `Activity`.

Something like this should work:

```
public void addPlayers(EditText nameOfPlayer, LinearLayout container,
    final List<String> playersNames) {
    final View addView;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (nameOfPlayer.getText().length() >= shortestNameLength) {
        addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_to_add_more_players,
            null);
        TextView textOut = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);
        final String currentName = nameOfPlayer.getText().toString();
        textOut.setText(currentName);
        playersNames.add(currentName);

        nameOfPlayer.setText("");
        Button buttonRemove = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
        buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // removing the name from the List
                playersNames.remove(currentName);

                ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
            }
        });
        container.addView(addView);
    }
}
```

(you should also take a look at the [**Java Naming Conventions**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html))